# Conditional probability density function calculation using cdf

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $Z = 2A + B$ where $A$ and $B$ are uniformly distributed between $[0,1]$. I want to find $f_{A|Z=z}(a|z)$ using cdf. Then:

\begin{equation}
F_{A|Z=z}(a|z) = P(A < a) = P(\frac{z-B}{2} < a) = P(z-2a < B)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
F_{A|Z=z}(a|z) = 1-F_B(z-2a) 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f_{A|Z=z}(a|z) = 2f_B(z-2a) 
\end{equation}

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Aren’t you basically done? We know the distribution of $B$. Note: it’s worth specifying the region of validity when you write your final answer.

Comment: @BenjaminWang what is $f_B(z-2a)$ in here?

Comment: The PDF of a $U[0,1]$ r.v. is $f(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$ and zero otherwise

Comment: But anyway I think this is wrong because you haven't used the definition of conditional PDF https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/20/20.2

Answer (score 1):

$$P(A \leq a | z) = \frac{P(A \leq a,  Z \in [z-dz,z])}{P(Z \in [z-dz,z])} = \frac{P(A \leq a,  2A+B \in [z-dz,z])}{P(Z \in [z-dz,z])}  $$
$$ = \int_{0}^a \frac{P(A \in [s-ds,s],  B \in [z-2A-dz,z-2A])}{P(Z \in [z-dz,z])}= \int_{0}^a \frac{P(A \in [s-ds,s],  B \in [z-2s+2ds-dz,z-2s])}{P(Z \in [z-dz,z])}$$
Applying Mean Value theorem and assuming continuity of $f_A(x)$ in the interval $[0,a]$, continuity of $f_B(x)$ at in the interval $[z-2a,z]$ and continuity of $f_Z(x)$ at $x = z$:
$$= \int_{0}^a \frac{f_A(s) f_B(z-2s) \ ds }{f_Z(z)} $$
Hence :
$$f_{A|Z}(a|z)= \frac{f_A(a) f_B(z-2a)}{f_Z(z)} $$.

This does not quite apply to your problem as uniform distribution has two discontinuities in its density function. But where ever the continuity conditions i mentioned holds, the above is the density function. I am hoping that this will help you in general.